# Ruby View render time increases on concurrency rails 4 passenger 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, phusion

My render time increase tremendously in concurrency load test.
With one user the render time is low but goes on increasing as i add users the rendering time goes on increasing.

render time for one user :
    Rendered shared/_enablers_comm_logo_new_permissionengine.html.erb (135    7.9ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_view_timeline.html.erb (3581.2ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_list_timeline.html.erb (3584.2ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_list.html.erb (3586.6ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_home_page.html.erb (5585.5ms)

render time for 20 users :
    Rendered shared/_enablers_comm_logo_new_permissionengine.html.erb (1891.2ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_view_timeline.html.erb (14219.5ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_list_timeline.html.erb (14236.3ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_list.html.erb (14253.2ms)
    Rendered shared/_enablers_home_page.html.erb (21757.8ms)

Also is erb files are not cached?? as my io utilization is high.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiling tool to get a grasp on the database queries?

Comment: yes pulled the database queries also and they remain same under load and for single user and is below 3 sec as combined queries time

Comment: Its hard to know why your views are running so slowly without any code. Have you setup any sort of fragment caching?

Comment: No not yet. Fragment caching can help to improve the timings but i am more interested in getting the reason why the render time shoots up in concurrency. As me passenger settings has min active instance as 30 so ideally 30 users should have got same render time till my cpu resources are free.